# Drivers License Exam (Getting random numbers for missed questions)

Tags: java

Was given some homework in my JAVA class, had to write a program for a driver license exam. It had to have the following methods:

*passed*. Returns true if the student passed the exam, or
false if the student failed

*totalCorrect*. Returns the total number of correctly answered
questions

*totalIncorrect*. Returns the total numner of incorrectly
answered questions

*questionsMissed*. An int array containing the question numbers
of the questions that the student missed

We'll so far I've done fine until I reach the questions missed section. We're supposed to recall the incorrect corrections, however when I call to it I get a weird number [I@55f96302. I've spent the last 2 hours looking at this program and I'm not sure what I've messed up on. Any help would greatly be appreciated. Thank You

```
public class DLE {

 private char[] key = { 'B', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D',
                        'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A' };
 private char[] answers;



 public DLE(char[] ans)
 {
    answers = ans;
 }

 public boolean passed ()
 {
  return (totalCorrect() > 14);
 }

 public int totalCorrect()
 {
  int correct = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < key.length; i++)
 {

 if (key[i] == answers[i])
  correct++;
 }
 return correct;
 }

 public int totalMissed()
 {
    int tmissed = 0;
    tmissed = key.length - totalCorrect();
    return tmissed;
 }

 public int[] questionsMissed()
 {

  int size = key.length - totalCorrect();

  int[] missed = {};
  if (size < 1)
  return missed;
  else
  missed = new int [size];

  int pos = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < key.length; i++)
  {
   if (key[i] != answers[i])
   {
    missed[pos] = (i + 1);
    pos = pos + 1;
   }
  }
  return missed;

 }
}
```

// Driver

```
public class driver
{

     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
      // accept keyboard input
       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter your answers below.\n");

      char[] answers = new char[20];

      // request an answer for each question
      for(int i = 0; i < answers.length; i++)
      {
            // get input until input is valid
            char input;

            do
            {
                  System.out.print(i + 1 + ". ");

                  // get character and make it upper case
                  input = Character.toUpperCase(keyboard.next().charAt(0));
            }
            while(input < 'A' || input >'D');

            // store answer
            answers[i] = input;
      }

      // print output here
      DLE driver = new DLE(answers) {};
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("You "+(driver.passed()?"passed" : "did not pass") + ".\n");
      System.out.println("Correct: " + driver.totalCorrect() + "\n");
      System.out.println("Incorrect: " + driver.totalMissed() + "\n");
      System.out.println("Questions missed: " + driver.questionsMissed());

  }
}
```

Comment: It's because you are printing out the array's toString() method when you call System.out.println(driver.questionsMissed());. The default toString() is the hash of the object. Instead, you want to print out each of the values in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Arrays.toString() utility method to print the array of integer.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
...
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(driver.questionsMissed()));
```